# csv file imported to windows from linux

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, csv, data-transfer

I wonder why is there a difference for both of the csv files mentioned below.

I got a table.csv file in Linux, after I send it out as attachment in mail then save and open it in my windows excel application, it was messy, the columns were not aligned with data scattered around.

But when I open an excel file and go to "Data" tab and click on "From text" from "get external data" category, then select the **same** csv file I used just now, then the output in table form is very well aligned and clean.

> My endgoal is to get the nicely aligned output directly from linux to window excel by attaching it in mail without taking extra step to go excel and select the get external data from text.

I can't really figure out why the two same csv file has such difference, to overcome this issue, do I have to write a script to manipulate the excel?

Thank you for any advice. I am really curious about this.

[image: first] the data is only in the first column (colA)

[image: second]
this is very well aligned in each column

[image: comparison]

Comment: What application are you using to open it in Windows when it looks scrambled?  You describe Excel handling the file fine, and your goal is to open it in Excel, so I'm missing what the problem is.  Windows uses CR+LF for end-of-line while Linux uses just LF.  If this is being prepared in Linux, any chance that the end-of-line is what's making the file appear scrambled?

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, both are open using excel application in windows. Thank you

Comment: It was mentioned in my endgoal? hmm.. I want to just click on the attachment file in my mail and it would be nicely formatted. Without extra step to open an excel first, then click those buttons. Thank you

Comment: The first example is putting all four values in a single cell.  It looks like a delimiter problem.  Maybe it is tab delimited instead of comma delimited and Excel isn't guessing correctly.  The email attachment shouldn't change anything, but maybe getting it into an email wrapper in Linus and extracting it in Windows is affecting it.  Try opening both files in a hex editor and compare the first few records.

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, I used Notepad++ to open both files. Surprisingly, the first one shows very well aligned data in invisible columns. But the second's shows garbled text. I'm not sure if it's had to do with the fact that I get the external data then save the file in .xlsx extension before I open it in notepad++. Thank you

Comment: A text editor won't do it.  You need a hex editor so you can see what each character is, including the non-display characters.  You're looking for differences in the delimiters and end-of-line characters, and anything else that's different between them.  That will identify exactly what is being interpreted differently.

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure if the new uploaded picture is clear enough for you, but for the one on top, in the text column, it shows exactly what's in my file, but not for the below one. [the image below shows plenty of ellipsis ...]

Comment: Wait, the messed up one is a CSV generated from the Excel file and the good one is the actual file?  The screenshot would be easier to use if it was big enough to read the translated values on the top one.  The next step would be to try and rule out the email as changing something.  It isn't clear if you're doing this on two separate computers, but try opening the original CSV file rather than an emailed copy (transfer via flash drive).  Also, there should be a wizard that lets you set the assumptions for opening the CSV.  Playing with those may let you open it properly and reveal the issue.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the exact problem.  Are you saying you've got the CSV file on the Windows machine, saved to the HDD from the email.  If you open Excel and then from there, import the CSV, it's properly formatted.  If instead, you right-click on the CSV and select opening it with Excel, it's messed up?

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, I'm using the same PC all this time, linux is also installed in this PC, so when I export the .csv from linux to windows, I'm still using the same PC. yes, the good one is the actual file. The translated values? do you mean the text column next to those numbers? It was actually some introduction text shows above my table. wizard ? erm, the original csv file in linux was nicely output until it was exported out to mail.

Comment: Hi @fixer1234, regarding on your latest comment. yesyes, that's the problem I'm facing !

Comment: I don't have ready access to Excel, but go into your settings and see what the defaults are for CSV files (delimiters, etc.).  If what I described in the previous comment is accurate, I suspect the issue is settings.  Excel has a lot of flexibility in handling variations in CSV files when you use the import wizard.  If you just right-click on a CSV file, everything has to perfectly match the default settings or Excel won't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

As fixer1234 mentioned, this most likely has to do with line endings in Linux vs Windows.  It depends on what the file is prepared in.  There's several questions on stack overflow and other sites asking how to fix this.  I imagine, if you save the file in windows, and then send it back to linux, and open it in vi, you'll see strange characters on that end as well (^M at the end of lines).

Without more details on what you're seeing, I can't really tell you how to fix it, but there's a few examples of how to fix it on one side or the other [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/134709/how-can-i-keep-the-code-formated-as-original-source-when-i-paste-them-to-vim)

If you provide a detailed example of what's happening, I can give a much clearer example on how to fix your problem.

Comment: Hi @trueCamelType, I have attached some screenshot for the worksheet, hope you could have a look at it. I'm not sure if I can fixed this by writing perl or shell script (to execute it in linux-where my original csv file is from), I wouldn't mind, since I have to add an extra column "Overall" to calculate the average marks. Thank you

Comment: @ExcelNovice If the only problem you are having, is when you default open a document in excel, that it isn't formatting correctly, that's not a problem at all.  Excel knows which column things should go in by being separated by commas (.csv files).  If you just put commas between he value, it will put a new column instead of a tab.  Without commas, all of it being in a single column is the expected outcome.